# Is there a simple way to get the Bourbaki dangerous bend symbol (without extra)?

Tags: symbols

I would like to put a Bourbaki dangerous bend symbol in my text. The LaTeX package `manfnt` allows to easily type the Knuth variant of the Bourbaki dangerous bend symbol. This variant is basically the Z-shaped dangerous band inside a signal diamond attached to a pole (`\dbend`). This variant is nice but height: it introduces extra interline (because of the pole). I am looking for a Z-shaped only version, a one that is ready to use.

Comment: this is unicode U+2621 so it should be in the stix/xits fonts.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Is that an uppercase _U_ I see before me?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen -- uh, yes.  (there *are* some exceptions.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Very interesting: any hint on how to type it in LaTeX  ?

Comment: for the stix fonts, the command `\danger` was proposed, but i'm not sure it's the final choice.

Answer (score 9):

A TikZ version with the height of a "Z". Width, height, rotation angle, line thickness, ... can easily be changed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz[
  line cap=but,
  line join=round,
  x=.5em,
  very thick,
  y=1*(height("Z")-\pgflinewidth)*(1-sin(10)),
  rotate=-10,
  rounded corners=1.5pt,
]\draw (1, 0) -- (0, 0) -- (1, 1) -- (0, 1);
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to adjust the size?

Comment: @N.Pullbacki (a) The whole symbol can be scaled by a canvas transformation, e.g. by factor 2: `transform canvas={scale=2}. (b) The coordinates can be scaled with TikZ option `scale` (or differently for x and y axis with `xscale` and `yscale`, the line width (the example uses `very thick`) can be set with TikZ option `line width`, and the value for `rounded corners` can be set differently.

Answer (score 7):

This implements Barbara Beeton's suggestion without loading the `stix` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{stixbbit}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{stixbbit}{m}{it}{<-> stix-mathbbit}{}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\stixdanger}{%
  {\usefont{U}{stixbbit}{m}{it}\symbol{"F6}}%
}

\begin{document}

This is the \stixdanger{} symbol.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like the slightly rotated version, partly because it's more clear that it's not a letter Z or a numeral 2. To get the rotation, it worked for me to use `\rotatebox[origin=c]{-10}{\stixdanger}`, with rotatebox being provided by the graphicx package.

Answer (score 4):

Find its [unicode](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2621/index.htm), see the [fonts](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2621/fontsupport.htm) which support it, search your system for [available fonts](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/font/fontlist.htm?text=%E2%98%A1%20-%20CAUTION%20SIGN%20%28U%2B2621%29) and do (Lua- or XeLaTeX needed):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\fontspec{code2000.ttf}\symbol{"2621}
\fontspec{quivira.otf}\symbol{"2621}
% or very dangerous...
\fontspec{symbola.ttf}\symbol{"2621}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Following @barbarabeeton comment, a stix version writes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stix}

\begin{document}
$\danger$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the package stix interferes very badly with my target journal template (article document + AmS packages): does a more selective package exist ? ((Note: I am ready to hack for own stuff, but I am not sure about the Journal editorial team behaviour: past experiences convince me to stick to classical stuff))

Comment: It seems like egreg's answer would be a variation on this that would avoid the clash with the stix package.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired in Egreg's answer below I present my own Bourbaki's dangerous bendsymbol:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{stixbbit}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{stixbbit}{m}{it}{
<-> stix-mathbbit
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixbbit}{U}{stixbbit}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\bend}{\mathord}{stixbbit}{"F6}
\newcommand*{\bendsymbol}{\ensuremath{\bend\hspace{-2mm}\bend\hspace{-2mm}\bend\hspace{-2mm}\bend}}
```

The original symbol would be the `\bend` symbol defined. I want it thicker too, that's why I define also the `\bendsymbol` symbol. It is true that it isn't the most elegant way to get it. However, it has (what I think is) and advantage with respect to Egreg's bend symbol, and is that it's defined as a `math ordinary symbol`, just like `\alpha`.

It is possible to rotate it if one wants, but I like it just like that.

[image]