# How to make the theorem environment flow around campa's code for TeXbook's bend symbol?

Tags: tikz-pgf, theorems

This is a follow up question to [this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604048/21685). How can I make campa's code for TeXbook's bend symbol work with the `theorem` environment?

Consider the following LaTeX code which I saved in a file called `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newenvironment{mydanger}[1]{%
  \sbox0{%
     \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
        \draw[rounded corners=.1] (-.05,-1.5)--++(0,2.55)--++(.1,0)--++(0,-2.55);
        \draw[fill=white,rounded corners=1] (0,1)--(1,0)--(0,-1)--(-1,0)--cycle;
        \draw[very thick](-.3,-1.5)--(.3,-1.5);
        \node at (0,0) {\small#1};
     \end{tikzpicture}
  }%       this space ^^^ is here for a reason!
  \par\medskip  \noindent
  \hangindent\wd0
  \parindent\hangindent
  \hangafter=-2
  \setbox0=\hbox to0pt{\hss\lower3ex\box0}%
  \dp0=0pt
  \box0
  \small
  \ignorespaces
 }{\par\smallskip}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{mydanger}{A}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mydanger}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{mydanger}{A}
\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}
\end{mydanger}
\end{document}
```

When I run this code with `lualatex test`, the following output is typeset:

[image: Bourbaki's bend symbol with the theorem environment]

I'd like the theorem paragraph to flow around the bend symbol like the regular paragraph above it.

---

**Important requirement**

The solution must be consistent with the possibility of adding margin notes via `\marginpar` inside the theorem. Therefore, for instance, a solution that encapsulates the theorem inside an invisible `tcolorbox` will not be an acceptable solution; see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/604700/21685).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather hacking solution. The implementation of `theorem` uses `trivlist`, which starts a new line. Basically what I did is to use `\patchcmd` to remove `trivlist` and redefine the `\item` command to make sure the output is consistent.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newenvironment{mydanger}[1]{%
  \sbox0{%
     \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
        \draw[rounded corners=.1] (-.05,-1.5)--++(0,2.55)--++(.1,0)--++(0,-2.55);
        \draw[fill=white,rounded corners=1] (0,1)--(1,0)--(0,-1)--(-1,0)--cycle;
        \draw[very thick](-.3,-1.5)--(.3,-1.5);
        \node at (0,0) {\small#1};
     \end{tikzpicture}
  }%       this space ^^^ is here for a reason!
  \par\medskip  \noindent
  \hangindent\wd0
  \parindent\hangindent
  \hangafter=-2
  \setbox0=\hbox to0pt{\hss\lower3ex\box0}%
  \dp0=0pt
  \box0
  \small
  \ignorespaces
 }{\par\smallskip}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@begintheorem}{\trivlist\item}{\bgroup\myitem}{}{\GenericError{}{unable to patch command}{}{}}

\patchcmd{\@opargbegintheorem}{\trivlist\item}{\bgroup\myitem}{}{\GenericError{}{unable to patch command}{}{}}

\def\@endtheorem{\egroup}
\def\@opargendtheorem{\egroup}
\def\myitem[#1]{#1~}
\makeatother



\begin{document}


\begin{mydanger}{A}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mydanger}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{mydanger}{A}
\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}
\end{mydanger}

\begin{mydanger}{B}
\begin{theorem}[Test Theorem]
\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}
\end{mydanger}

\end{document}
```

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newenvironment{mydanger}[1]{%
  \sbox0{%
     \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.3]
        \draw[rounded corners=.1] (-.05,-1.5)--++(0,2.55)--++(.1,0)--++(0,-2.55);
        \draw[fill=white,rounded corners=1] (0,1)--(1,0)--(0,-1)--(-1,0)--cycle;
        \draw[very thick](-.3,-1.5)--(.3,-1.5);
        \node at (0,0) {\small#1};
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \hspace*{3mm}
  }%       this space ^^^ is here for a reason!
  \par\medskip  \noindent
  \hangindent\wd0
  \parindent\hangindent
  \hangafter=-2
  \setbox0=\hbox to0pt{\hss\lower3ex\box0}%
  \dp0=0pt
  \box0
  \small
  \ignorespaces
 }{\par\smallskip}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@begintheorem}{\trivlist\item}{\bgroup\myitem}{}{\GenericError{}{unable to patch command}{}{}}
\patchcmd{\@opargbegintheorem}{\trivlist\item}{\bgroup\myitem}{}{\GenericError{}{unable to patch command}{}{}}

% also remove the spacing before Theorem
\patchcmd{\@begintheorem}{\hskip\labelsep}{}{}{\GenericError{}{unable to patch command}{}{}}
\patchcmd{\@opargbegintheorem}{\hskip\labelsep}{}{}{\GenericError{}{unable to patch command}{}{}}

\def\@endtheorem{\egroup}
\def\@opargendtheorem{\egroup}
\def\myitem[#1]{\noindent {#1}~}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\meaning\@begintheorem
\makeatother

\begin{mydanger}{A}
\lipsum[1]
\end{mydanger}

\vspace{1cm}

\begin{mydanger}{A}
\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}
\end{mydanger}

\begin{mydanger}{B}
\begin{theorem}[Test Theorem]
\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}
\end{mydanger}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't test it right now, since I'm not near a computer with a TeX installation. One thing, though. In your solution tthe text flows jaggedly round the sign. Compare this to the way the paragraph flows evenly round the sign in the TeXbook, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28hcm.png), Could you emulate this even flow?

Comment: I also included a second version below, which emulates the TeX book layout.

Comment: Thank you! I'll test it tomorrow.

Comment: Why does the second piece of code [print](https://imgur.com/a/pKFQltL) a strange first line?

Comment: I used `\meaning` to analyze the command. Just forgot about it, you can simply delete it in the document body.

Comment: I'll accept your answer, because you met the requirements I specified in my original post. However, your code fails to work in the actual document I'm working on. In fact, just copying your preamble to my preamble without even using the `\mydanger` command in the body of the document, causes the compilation to fail with the error message `unable to patch command`. Unfortunately, I don't have the time currently to debug it.

Comment: If `\patchcmd` doesn't work, you can simply extract the definition of `\@begintheorem` and manually redefine it with `\renewcommand`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. Could you change your code accordingly, please?

Comment: @EvanAad Can you give a more relevant example of which document class/packages that you are using? It is likely that `\patchcmd` doesn't not work because of some changes to the definition of `\theorem`.