# tcolorbox frame + TikZ picture + marginpar

Tags: tikz-pgf, tcolorbox, theorems, marginpar

In [a reply to another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604575/21685) user leandriis gave code that surrounds a theorem environment with a rectangle that has a TikZ picture in a corner. The following is copied almost verbatim from leandriis' answer with the exception of an additional comment that has been added near the end.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Definition of \mydangersymbol taken from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604048/134144
\newcommand{\mydangersymbol}[1]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(x.base)]
         \draw[rounded corners=.01em] (-.05em,-1.3em)rectangle(.05em,.9em);
         \draw[fill=white,rounded corners=1] (0,.8em)--(.8em,0)--(0,-.8em)--(-.8em,0)--cycle;
         \draw[very thick,line cap=round](-.3em,-1.3em)--(.3em,-1.3em);
         \node(x) at (0,0em) {\normalfont\sffamily\small#1};
      \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\NewTColorBox{mydangerenv}{+O{}}{%
    enhanced,
    sharp corners, 
    colback=white,
    coltitle=black,
    title={\mydangersymbol{#1}},
    attach boxed title to top left ={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2-4pt,
                                     yshifttext=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2-4pt, 
                                     xshift=-\tcboxedtitlewidth/2+0.25mm},
    boxed title style={colback=white,
                       colframe=white, 
                       sharp corners, 
                       boxsep=0pt, 
                       boxrule=0pt, 
                       bottom=3pt, 
                       halign title=flush center},
  boxrule=0.5mm,
  top=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2+5pt,
  boxsep=5pt,
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{mydangerenv}[A]
\begin{theorem}
%\marginpar{Hello, world!}
\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}
\end{mydangerenv}

\end{document}
```

This code compiles successfully (I use LuaLaTeX), and typesets as follows:

[image: A theorem environment surrounded by a rectangle with a TikZ picture in its top left forner]

If I now delete the `%` character from the last comment, so that the `\marginpar` command is visible to the TeX engine, and recompile the code, the compilation fails, and the following error message appears in the log file:

```
! LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.47 \marginpar
             {Hello, world!}
? 
! Emergency stop.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.47 \marginpar
             {Hello, world!}
You've lost some text.  Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.
```

How can this problem be corrected, so that the code typesets as follows:

[image: Rectangle together with a margin note]

---

**NB**

I used `\marginpar` for simplicity, but I'm actually interested in [campa's `\marginstuff` command](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604376/21685). Hopefully the answer to the question as posed will help me solve the problem with `\marginstuff`, which gives a similar `Not in outer par mode` error message.

Comment: I do not think that  `\marginpar` can work inside more or less anything. You can move it before or after the colorbox, though. You can create "callouts" by hand like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/295903/refer-to-a-node-in-tikz-that-will-be-defined-in-the-future-two-passes if you want something more controllable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alternative I:** load the package `marginnote` and use `\marginnote{Hello, world!}`

[image: m]

**Alternative II**: Load `\tcbuselibrary{documentation}`  and use   `\tcbdocmarginnote{Hello, world!}`.  (It loads `marginote`)

[image: d]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{documentation} % to use \tcbdocmarginnote{..}, loads marginnote <<<<
%\usepackage{marginnote} %to use \marginnote{...} <<<<
    

\usepackage{tikz}

% Definition of \mydangersymbol taken from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604048/134144
\newcommand{\mydangersymbol}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(x.base)]
        \draw[rounded corners=.01em] (-.05em,-1.3em)rectangle(.05em,.9em);
        \draw[fill=white,rounded corners=1] (0,.8em)--(.8em,0)--(0,-.8em)--(-.8em,0)--cycle;
        \draw[very thick,line cap=round](-.3em,-1.3em)--(.3em,-1.3em);
        \node(x) at (0,0em) {\normalfont\sffamily\small#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\NewTColorBox{mydangerenv}{+O{}}{%
    enhanced,
    sharp corners, 
    colback=white,
    coltitle=black,
    title={\mydangersymbol{#1}},
    attach boxed title to top left ={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2-4pt,
        yshifttext=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2-4pt, 
        xshift=-\tcboxedtitlewidth/2+0.25mm},
    boxed title style={colback=white,
        colframe=white, 
        sharp corners, 
        boxsep=0pt, 
        boxrule=0pt, 
        bottom=3pt, 
        halign title=flush center},
    boxrule=0.5mm,
    top=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2+5pt,
    boxsep=5pt,
}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{mydangerenv}[A]
        \begin{theorem}
        \tcbdocmarginnote{Hello, world!}    % <<<<  
%       \marginnote{Hello, world!}% <<<<    
            \lipsum[1]
        \end{theorem}
    \end{mydangerenv}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tested the `marginnote` solution you suggested in Alternative I. The code compiled successfully, but no margin note was produced in the typeset output.

Comment: Never mind, I've figured it out: the code needs to be compiled twice.