# How to surround a theorem/definition environment with a rectangle that has a TikZ picture in the corner?

Tags: tikz-pgf, theorems

In another question user campa [showed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604048/21685) how to use TikZ to draw a certain picture (an adaptation of the [Bourbaki dangerous bend symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bourbaki_dangerous_bend_symbol&oldid=1014220551)).

How can I draw a rectangle around a theorem/definition/etc. environment that has campa's picture at the top left corner?

[image: A framed theorem with a TikZ picture in the corner]

I'd like to be able to achieve this using code similar to the following:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{mydangerenv}[A]
\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}
\end{mydangerenv}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a `tcolorbox`-based attempt:

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Definition of \mydangersymbol taken from: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/604048/134144
\newcommand{\mydangersymbol}[1]{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(x.base)]
         \draw[rounded corners=.01em] (-.05em,-1.3em)rectangle(.05em,.9em);
         \draw[fill=white,rounded corners=1] (0,.8em)--(.8em,0)--(0,-.8em)--(-.8em,0)--cycle;
         \draw[very thick,line cap=round](-.3em,-1.3em)--(.3em,-1.3em);
         \node(x) at (0,0em) {\normalfont\sffamily\small#1};
      \end{tikzpicture}%
}


\NewTColorBox{mydangerenv}{+O{}}{%
    enhanced,
    sharp corners, 
    colback=white,
    coltitle=black,
    title={\mydangersymbol{#1}},
    attach boxed title to top left ={yshift=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2-4pt,
                                     yshifttext=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2-4pt, 
                                     xshift=-\tcboxedtitlewidth/2+0.25mm},
    boxed title style={colback=white,
                       colframe=white, 
                       sharp corners, 
                       boxsep=0pt, 
                       boxrule=0pt, 
                       bottom=3pt, 
                       halign title=flush center},
  boxrule=0.5mm,
  top=-\tcboxedtitleheight/2+5pt,
  boxsep=5pt,
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{mydangerenv}[A]
\begin{theorem}
\lipsum[1]
\end{theorem}
\end{mydangerenv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. If I wish to tweak it a little so that the sign's right corner is aligned with the rectangle's top edge, how should I go about it?

Comment: Play with the `yshift` values and the `top=` value.

Comment: @EvanAad: I've just updated my answer accordingly. The value of `yshift` was determined manually, so there may still be room for improvement.