# How to create an environment that flanks its content from the top and from the bottom with lines, the top of which contains a picture in the middle?

Tags: environments

I'd like the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

% macro definitions...

\begin{document}

\begin{signenv}{A}
\lipsum[1]
\end{signenv}

\end{document}
```

To produce this:

[image: A top bottom frame with a sign]

In words: the `signenv` environment's paragraph is flanked from the top and from the bottom by two lines the length of the paragraph. In the middle of the top line there's a diamond with a letter inside it. The letter is determined by the mandatory parameter passed to the `signenv` environment. There's some space between the diamond and the top line.

`signenv` must not embed the paragraph inside a TeX box/a `tcolorbox` etc.

Comment: Realgarding your last paragraph: what's the reason for not wanting to use tcolorbox?

Comment: @leandriis: I've [tried](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/604573/21685) using `tcolorbox`s before, but found them to be very problematic when used in combination with programmable margin notes, a feature that I require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{signenv}[1]{%
\par
\smallskip
\noindent\hrulefill\ %
\begin{picture}(20,20)(0,0)
\put(10,0){\makebox(0,0){#1}}
\put(0,0){\line(1,1){10}}
\put(0,0){\line(1,-1){10}}
\put(20,0){\line(-1,1){10}}
\put(20,0){\line(-1,-1){10}}
\end{picture}\ %
\hrulefill
\par
\bigskip}
{\par\medskip\noindent\hrulefill\par\smallskip}

\begin{document}

\begin{signenv}{A}
\lipsum[1]
\end{signenv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is great. Could you please create the lettered diamond in its own macro `sign{A}`/`sign{B}`/etc. so that I can use it inline in order to explain what each of the lettered diamonds mean? E.g. "The symbol \sign{C} means that the enclosed paragraph is a caveat, whereas the symbol \sign{A} means that it's an anecdote."

Comment: @EvanAad you can do that, just cut the bit from begin picture to end picture and stick it in `\newcommand\mydiamond[1]{.....`

Comment: But then the diamond drops below the line of text.

Comment: @EvanAad well the rule is on the baseline and you wanted the angle of the diamond on there, you can change the `(0,0)` second argument to `(0,10)` or whatever in the self standing version.

Comment: Thanks. One last request, please. The content I intend to surround with this environment is theorems. And when used with theorems the lines are too far from the theorem, as seen [here](https://imgur.com/1xmAzjC). Could you please make the lines closer to the content? Also, if possible, the top line should never be in the bottom of a page, detached from the following content, nor should the bottom line ever be in the top of a page, detached from the preceding content.

Comment: @EvanAad really you can adjust that yourself, I added `\smallskip` and `\medskip` in various places you could change them to `\vspace{5cm}` or whatever you need. Or change the spacing specified in your theorem declarations.

Comment: I see. And keeping the lines on the same page as the content? Can this be arranged?

Comment: @EvanAad add `\nopagebreak` before any skip

Comment: It doesn't work. But I'll ask about it in a different post, so I can give a minimal example to demonstrate the issue. Thanks for all your help!