# How can I prevent environment contents from being broken across pages?

Tags: environments, page-breaking

Consider the following code, copied almost verbatim from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/605221/21685), except that two calls to `\lipsum`,

```
\lipsum[1-4]

\lipsum[5][1-10]
```

have been added inside the document's body.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{signenv}[1]{%
\par
\smallskip
\noindent\hrulefill\ %
\begin{picture}(20,20)(0,0)
\put(10,0){\makebox(0,0){#1}}
\put(0,0){\line(1,1){10}}
\put(0,0){\line(1,-1){10}}
\put(20,0){\line(-1,1){10}}
\put(20,0){\line(-1,-1){10}}
\end{picture}\ %
\hrulefill
\par
\bigskip}
{\par\medskip\noindent\hrulefill\par\smallskip}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\lipsum[5][1-10]

\begin{signenv}{A}
\lipsum[1]
\end{signenv}

\end{document}
```

The resulting PDF file has two pages, as follows.

[image: signenv across a page break with the upper line separated]

As can be seen, the top line drawn by the `signenv` environment appears on a different page than the paragraph contained inside the environment. Similarly, if you replace the first two calls to `\lipsum` by

```
\lipsum[1-3]

\lipsum[4][1]
```

the bottom line drawn by the `signenv` environment appears on a different page than the paragraph contained inside the environment.

[image: signenv across a page break with the lower line separated.]

How can I arrange it so that both the top and the bottom lines of the `signenv` environment will always appear on the same page as the text inside the environment?

Answer (score 9):

as I commented under the original code, you can add `\nopagebreak`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{signenv}[1]{%
\par
\smallskip
\noindent\hrulefill\ %
\begin{picture}(20,20)(0,0)
\put(10,0){\makebox(0,0){#1}}
\put(0,0){\line(1,1){10}}
\put(0,0){\line(1,-1){10}}
\put(20,0){\line(-1,1){10}}
\put(20,0){\line(-1,-1){10}}
\end{picture}\ %
\hrulefill
\par
\nopagebreak
\bigskip}
{\par\nopagebreak\medskip\noindent\hrulefill\par\smallskip}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\lipsum[5][1-10]

\begin{signenv}{A}
\lipsum[1]
\end{signenv}

\end{document}
```

Comment: but better don't start or end in the environment with a list ;-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer who would do such a thing?

Comment: Thank you. What if I don't want the `\bigskip` after the top line nor the `\medskip` before the bottom line? Is there a `\noskip` that works with `\nopagebreak`? Does the `\nopagebreak` work before `\par`?

Comment: no after the par but you can delete the skips @EvanAad

Comment: Thank you. One more thing, please. Your solution doesn't work when the `\lipsum[1]` that's inside the `signenv` environment is inserted into a `theorem` environment: `\begin{signenv}{A}\begin{theorem}\lipsum[1]\end{theorem}\end{signenv}`. Could you please look into it? (Of course, you need to add `\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}` to the preamble.)

Comment: see @UlrikeFischer's first comment....

Comment: @EvanAad add after the `\bigskip`   `\csname @afterheading\endcsname`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks. This handles the upper line. Is there a way to handle the bottom line too?